# Django many-to-many relationship with through table, how to prevent it doing a lot of queries?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am working on an API for a D&D tool where I have campaigns, and people can be members of campaigns. I need to store extra information for each member of the campaign, so I am using a through model.

```py
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owned_campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='campaigns', through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_dm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I want to fetch all campaigns that the user is a member of, I can simply do something like this:

```py
>>> from auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> campaigns = user.campaigns.select_related('owner')
>>> print(campaign)
```

This does an INNER JOIN to fetch the owner of the campaign, so that prevents having to do an extra query. Great!

However, when I also want to return the array of members (with the nested user info for each member), then it does one extra query to fetch the members, and then one extra query *for every member* to fetch the user object.

I am noticing this specifically in Django REST Framework where I have serializers like this:

```py
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ["is_dm", "user"]


class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    members = MembershipSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='membership_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you have a campaign with 6 members, then this results in 8 queries all in total, which seems silly to me.

I had hoped that `prefetch_related` would solve this problem:

```py
>>> campaigns = user.campaigns.select_related('owner').prefetch_related()
>>> campaigns[0].members.all()[0].name
```

But this still does 3 queries: one for the campaign (inner joined with the user table for the owner), one for the membership, and one for that first user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prefetch_related` can definitely help here, but it would depend on how you use the relations.

If you want to use `Campaign`'s `members` field, then:

```
>>> campaigns = user.campaigns.select_related('owner').prefetch_related('members')
>>> campaigns[0].members.all()[0].name
```

This will result in two queries:

1. get the `campaign` with a left outer join to get the `owner`
2. fetch all related members (already `User` instances).

If you want to use the relation of `Campaign` to `Membership` - that is, `membership_set` like how you used it in your serializer:

```
>>> campaigns = user.campaigns.select_related('owner').prefetch_related('membership_set__user')
>>> campaigns[0].membership_set.all()[0].user.name
```

This will result in three queries:

1. get the `campaign` with a left outer join to get the `owner`
2. fetch all related `Membership` instances
3. fetch all related `Users` from the `user` foreign key of `Membership` (based on results of #2)

**EDIT**:

To reduce the queries even further for the 2nd approach, you can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to specify a custom queryset, where you can use `select_related` to grab the `User` from `Membership`:

```
>>> campaigns = user.campaigns.select_related('owner').prefetch_related(Prefetch('membership_set', queryset=Membership.objects.all().select_related('user')))
>>> campaigns[0].membership_set.all()[0].user.name
```

This will do a join on `Membership` and the related `Users` which should then finally result to only 2 queries.

Comment: Thanks! Your second example is indeed much better. It's still doing a request too many in my mind though: first it fetches all user ids from the membership table, then fetches those users with a single query 'where id IN (1, 2)`. So yes, it is better than what I had before, but why doesn't it just do a JOIN with membership and user right away? 

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it doesn't answer your question about why the join on membership and user is not done right away. Basically `membership_set` will only grab the related `Membership` instances which only has the `User` foreign key. To get to the next level (get the full user instance), we need `membership_set__user`.

Comment: Yes I did understand that the 2nd bit of code results in 3 queries, but in my mind this is kind of a problem with Django, since the last 2 queries *could* be combined into one with a JOIN. So I guess I just wish that `prefetch_related('membership_set__user')` would be smarter about this, and fetch membership inner joined with user.

Comment: It's clear to me now. Yes that is also supported. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was after!